# Git Bash изменить домашний каталог

Tags: git, git-bash

Установил клиента Git, для изучения и дальнейшего использования был выбран *Git Bash*, и вроде все работает, но есть один нюанс: *Каталог по умолчанию*, почему то установлен сетевой диск, хотелось бы его изменить, как это сделать?

**OS version: Windows 7 x64;**

**Git version: 2.6.3-64-bit;**

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7017143/5000805

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Решение было найдено [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7365221/5610621)

Необходимо изменить ярлык запуска *Git Bash*:

1. Вызываем контекстное меню для ярлыка: Клик правой кнопкой мыши по ярлыку, в открывшемся меню выбираем свойства.
2. Устанавливаем необходимый путь: В поле *Рабочая папка* устанавливаем необходимый путь.
3. Так же мне потребовалось изменить строку запуска: в поле *Объект* удаляем в конце строки `--cd-to-home`.

Запускаем клиента и убеждаемся в что что команда `pwd` отдает необходимый нам каталог

Answer (score 2):

Необходимо в проводнике вызывать контекстное меню правой кнопкой мыши и выбрать пункт **Git Bush here**. Git Bush автоматически откроется в выбранной папке без изменения свойств ярлыка.